# sqlite query android java array

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Hi can I do this??,

```
int[] ids=new int[]{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10};

db.execSQL(DELETE FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id NOT IN ?,ids);
```

basically I want to delete all the rows that doesn't match my ids array.

Comment: SO where is the problem? `ids.toString` will return object name

Comment: ids.toString become [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] and de array should be something like this (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

Comment: I believe you answered your own question there...

Comment: you are rigth,to string give the object name. can I convert ids into (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,8,10) to use in a sqlite query like that one?

Comment: Ahh sorry - as @Smit mentioned: calling `toString()` on an array will return the instance name of the array. If you were to use an `ArrayList` instead you'd get [1,2,3,4,5...] returned.
Anyways, using brackets in the SQL statement will fail.

Comment: @Xenione Yes you can do that but also you will have to do some string Operation to that. As  Darwind said you will have to replace `[]` with `()`

Comment: so I know there is a way to convert array into a select arguments query but I don't remember,crap!! thanks any way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
java.util.Arrays.toString(ids).replace('[', '(').replace(']', ')')
```

to convert the array to a suitable SQL where clause format

Comment: would this work for an arrayList of strings? or does something need to be modified?

Answer (score 3):

So your problem is that you placed only one placeholder which will be replaced only with one value and array of args should have only one item. It should potentially work if you had 9x **`?`** for each item in array.

It works as one placeholder - one value **(same order)**. I wrote for you this snippet of code. Check it out.

```
int[] ids = new int[] {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10};
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("delete from table where column_id not in (");
for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    query.append("?");
    if (i < ids.length - 1) {
        query.append(",");
    }
}
query.append(")");
db.execSQL(query.toString(), ids);
```

Now it should works. Also **`?`** character in dynamically created query is called **placeholder** and each placeholder will be replaced with value from `String[]` in same order.

I pretty recommend an usage of placeholders, whenever you will work with database. This approach is cleaner, safer and better looking.

### Update for API 11+

```
public int delete() {
    int[] ids = new int[] {1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10};
    String[] args = new String[ids.length];
    StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
    query.append("delete from table where column_id not in (");
    SQLiteStatement stmt = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        args[i] = String.valueOf(ids[i]);
        query.append("?");
        if (i < ids.length - 1) {
            query.append(",");
        }
    }
    query.append(")");
    stmt = db.compileStatement(query.toString());
    stmt.bindAllArgsAsStrings(args);
    return stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
}
```

Comment: @Smit `executeUpdateDelete();` is only from API 11.

Comment: Oh I got it its for Android sqlLite.